# Special characters are parsed as �

Tags: javascript, .net, character-encoding

For context, have .NET Core web application which contains a React app. When adding German translations to the app (containing all kinds of special characters such as ä, ö, ...), they show up as �.
The translations are usually kept in a json file which we import in the react component. We also tried adding the file to the wwwroot and downloading it from there, but it gives the same result.
The HTML uses utf-8, so we don't know what's causing these characters to be parsed that way.

Are we missing some setting? Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Please show the code you're using - it's hard to guess what's wrong otherwise. I would also recommend trying to add diagnostics to trace what data you have where - ideally by logging one specific character that you know is non-ASCII. Log the UTF-16 value *as an integer* so that you know it's not the logging causing problems.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. It's funny, as I was preparing a code example for you and saving the json file containing the translations, I got prompted with a message that my json file was not Unicode encoded and asked me if I wanted to save it with that format. Never had that message before, but I seems that all of my files weren't using the Unicode format. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, my files weren't saved in Unicode format. Case closed!